# How to get data which has Max Date in linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Here is a linq query, and the table "Timesheet_Log" has DT_CR Column with type DateTime and I want to get the query with latest DT_CR Date, how is it possible?

```
  var getEmployeeNames = (from emps in reslandentity.EMPLOYEE
                                join timesheet in reslandentity.TIMESHEET on emps.ID equals timesheet.RES_ID
                                join weekcal in reslandentity.WEEK_CALENDER on timesheet.WEEK_CAL_ID equals weekcal.ID
                                join log in reslandentity.TIMESHEET_LOG on timesheet.ID equals log.TIMESHEET_ID
                                join workflow in reslandentity.TIMESHEET_WORKFLOW on log.WORKFLOW_ID equals workflow.ID                                    
                                where weekcal.WEEK_START_DT.Month == month                                    
                                orderby log.DT_CR select new TimesheetModel
                                {
                                    EMP_ID = emps.ID,
                                    EMPLOYEE_NAME = emps.FIRST_NAME + " " + emps.LAST_NAME,
                                    RES_TYPE = workflow.ORG_RES_TYPE,
                                    EMP_STATUS = workflow.ACTION,
                                    SDate = weekcal.WEEK_START_DT,
                                    EDate = weekcal.WEEK_END_DT,
                                    DT_CR=log.DT_CR
                                }).Distinct().ToList();
   model.GetTimeSheetDetails = getEmployeeNames;
```

Please Help me to get the Query.

Comment: You want single model with latest date? If you want list of models, then please specify by what condition you want to select them

Comment: I should get data as Max(DT_CR) , but strucked how to write.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want to get. There is no grouping in your query - from what data you want to select max date?

Comment: ToList() is used, do you need to get the max date as single record from all records? Then use FirstOrDefault() after taking max range in where condition or use max e.g. var q=(from n in context.Tablename where...).Select(x=>x.nameofcolumn).Max();

Comment: You have an order by. You can then use `.Take(1)` (not sure how that is written in non-method syntax) to take the first item from the ordered list. You might want to order descending though to get the max date.

Comment: An ORM is the wrong tool to use for analysis. Joining more than two **entities** it's a very strong sign that something is seriously wrong - the mapping of tables to entities is wrong at the very least. A view that returns the desired results is infinitely faster **and** easier to maintain and optimize. Eg - how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not made it clear if you expect just a single result or a list of results (1 per timesheet).

If you just need a single result the answer by lti Tyangi will be fine.

If you need a result per timesheet you could try the following:

```
var getEmployeeNames = (from emps in reslandentity.EMPLOYEE
                            join timesheet in reslandentity.TIMESHEET on emps.ID equals timesheet.RES_ID
                            join weekcal in reslandentity.WEEK_CALENDER on timesheet.WEEK_CAL_ID equals weekcal.ID
                            join mxLog in (
                                from lg in reslandentity.TIMESHEET_LOG
                                group lg by lg.TIMESHEET_ID into lgGrp
                                select new {lgGrp.Key, DT_CR = lgGrp.Max(x => x.DT_CR)}
                            ) on timesheet.ID equals mxLog.Key
                            join log in reslandentity.TIMESHEET_LOG on new { a = mxLog.Key, b = mxLog.DT_CR} equals new{ a = log.TIMESHEET_ID, b = log.DT_CR}
                            join workflow in reslandentity.TIMESHEET_WORKFLOW on log.WORKFLOW_ID equals workflow.ID                                    
                            where weekcal.WEEK_START_DT.Month == month                                    
                            orderby log.DT_CR select new TimesheetModel
                            {
                                EMP_ID = emps.ID,
                                EMPLOYEE_NAME = emps.FIRST_NAME + " " + emps.LAST_NAME,
                                RES_TYPE = workflow.ORG_RES_TYPE,
                                EMP_STATUS = workflow.ACTION,
                                SDate = weekcal.WEEK_START_DT,
                                EDate = weekcal.WEEK_END_DT,
                                DT_CR=log.DT_CR
                            }).Distinct().ToList();
   model.GetTimeSheetDetails = getEmployeeNames;
```

here we join onto a grouping of the logs per timesheet to get the maximum date per timesheet, and then join to the logs based on both the id of the timesheet and that date

Comment: Thanks @James S, linq has complicated behaviour, it takes group by in different way

Answer (score 0):

```
 var getEmployeeNames = (from emps in reslandentity.EMPLOYEE
                            join timesheet in reslandentity.TIMESHEET on emps.ID equals timesheet.RES_ID
                            join weekcal in reslandentity.WEEK_CALENDER on timesheet.WEEK_CAL_ID equals weekcal.ID
                            join log in reslandentity.TIMESHEET_LOG on timesheet.ID equals log.TIMESHEET_ID
                            join workflow in reslandentity.TIMESHEET_WORKFLOW on log.WORKFLOW_ID equals workflow.ID                                    
                            where weekcal.WEEK_START_DT.Month == month                                    
                            //orderby log.DT_CR 
                            select new TimesheetModel
                            {
                                EMP_ID = emps.ID,
                                EMPLOYEE_NAME = emps.FIRST_NAME + " " + emps.LAST_NAME,
                                RES_TYPE = workflow.ORG_RES_TYPE,
                                EMP_STATUS = workflow.ACTION,
                                SDate = weekcal.WEEK_START_DT,
                                EDate = weekcal.WEEK_END_DT,
                                DT_CR=log.DT_CR
                            }).OrderByDescending(x=>x.DT_CR).FirstorDefault();
```

OR

```
 var getEmployeeNames = (from emps in reslandentity.EMPLOYEE
                            join timesheet in reslandentity.TIMESHEET on emps.ID equals timesheet.RES_ID
                            join weekcal in reslandentity.WEEK_CALENDER on timesheet.WEEK_CAL_ID equals weekcal.ID
                            join log in reslandentity.TIMESHEET_LOG on timesheet.ID equals log.TIMESHEET_ID
                            join workflow in reslandentity.TIMESHEET_WORKFLOW on log.WORKFLOW_ID equals workflow.ID                                    
                            where weekcal.WEEK_START_DT.Month == month                                    
                            //orderby log.DT_CR 
                            select new TimesheetModel
                            {
                                EMP_ID = emps.ID,
                                EMPLOYEE_NAME = emps.FIRST_NAME + " " + emps.LAST_NAME,
                                RES_TYPE = workflow.ORG_RES_TYPE,
                                EMP_STATUS = workflow.ACTION,
                                SDate = weekcal.WEEK_START_DT,
                                EDate = weekcal.WEEK_END_DT,
                                DT_CR=log.DT_CR
                            }).OrderByDescending(x=>x.DT_CR).ToList().Take(1);
```

Comment: Getting Error like "The specified type member 'DT_CR' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."

Comment: There is a typo in your answer. In both cases you have accidentally commented out the select as well as the original order by.

Comment: Thanks Chris, @sanjay: I hope you must not have copied the same(commented select).